# Getting rid of the dollar sign?

Tags: php

Ok so i am importing a csv via a PHP script I am writing and the spreadsheet has values like $4090,00 and i need to insert these values in a mysql decimal field using PHP. Is there an easy way to get rid of the $ if its present in PHP

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With str_replace, or even trim :

```
$str = str_replace('$', '', $str);
$str = trim($str, '$'); // only delete $ at start or end of the string
```

There are many solutions for this. Also, please note you have to use the period separator for decimals and integer part, not a comma.

Comment: Oops, typed too fast I guess :p. Thanks, I edited. But it's kinda harsh to -1 because of this, OP can obviously understand the pattern here.

Answer (score 6):

```
$value = "$4090,00";
$value = preg_replace('/[\$,]/', '', $value);
```

Comment: Is this generally faster than str_replace()?

Comment: Nope, I think in simple examples like this one str_replace is always more efficient

Answer (score 3):

Sure, you can use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) for this:

```
$nodollars = str_replace('$', '', $some_string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`sscanf`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.sscanf.php) if the input has a rigid format.