# Making the money value with only numbers

Tags: php

I just posted this question [link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4118080/getting-rid-of-the-dollar-sign) about 5 minutes ago and I forgot to mention that the format was like this

```
"$2,090.99 "
```

I need the final value like

```
"209099"
```

Striping the final extra space and getting rid of any other punctuation in the money value with php so i can store into a mysql decimal 10,2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a regular expression to replace everything that is not a digit:

```
$output = preg_replace('/\D/', '', $str);
```

`\D` is equivalent to `[^\d]` that is equivalent to `[^0-9]`.

Answer (score 6):

You might be better off using PHP 5.3's [`MessageFormatter`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.messageformatter.php), [`Locale`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.locale.php) and [`Intl`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) classes if you'll be handling different locales and currency formats. The `msgfmt_parse()` method might just be what you need.